# Defaults for slipped hashes and slurpy auto variables

Tags: raku

Is there a technique to pass along the default value of a hash when slipped into a sub call?

```
my %hash is default(222)=(a=>0,b=>111);

sub test {say %_.default};   #using automatic parameter

sub test2(%h) {say %h.default};   #explicit position parameter

test |%hash;  #outputs (Any)

test2 %hash   #outputs 222
```

The default of the input `%hash` is lost when slipped into the sub `test`. Is it possible to have the default in the slip? Cheers

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
my %hash is default(222)=(a=>0,b=>111);
sub test {say %_.default};   #using automatic parameter
test |%hash;  #outputs (Any)
```

Slipping by definition means turning a container into a list of its elements. So you're not passing the hash, but instead its contents.

[`%_`](https://docs.perl6.org/language/functions#Automatic_signatures) collects *copies* of the passed named arguments. It's a hash local to the block its in with no relationship to a hash used to slip arguments in. Its default is the default default, which is `Any`, just like it is with a `my` declared hash:

```
my %foo;
say %foo.default; # (Any)
```

> Is there a technique to pass along the default value of a hash when slipped into a sub call?

You could do this:

```
my %hash is default(222)=(a=>0,b=>111);
sub test {say %_<hash-default-for-test>} 
test |%hash, :hash-default-for-test(%hash.default);  #outputs 222
```

I picked the key string 'hash-default-for-test' because that's unlikely enough to occur as a normal key for any hash that it's reasonable to take the theoretical risk of accidental key collision.